# A question on the  theorem of Minkowski-Hlawka 

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, lattices

The Minkowski-Hlawka theorem (as stated by Gruber in his lovely book *Convex and Discrete Geometry*) says that *if $S$ is a Jordan measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with volume < 1. Then there is a lattice $L \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with determinant $1$ which contains no point of $S$, with the possible exception of the origin.*

In the special case where the set $S$ is a star-shaped body (with respect to the origin), this 
inequality can be written as 
$$
1 < \text{vol}(S)/\Delta(S) ,
$$
where $\Delta(S)$ is the *critical determinant* of $S$ (i.e., the infimum of the determinants of all lattices that intersect $S$ only at the origin).

**Question.** *Does the the linear-invariant functional $S \mapsto \text{vol}(S)/\Delta(S)$ attain its greatest lower bound when defined on (1) the space of star-shaped (compact) bodies and (2) the space of convex bodies that contain the origin as an interior point.*

I'm really just interested in the question of existence of minima and specially interested in the case of convex bodies. In any case, even in the "easy" case of $0$-symmetric convex bodies in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where the existence of minima is obvious, the minimum value is still just a conjecture (the Reinhardt conjecture).

Comment: related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125531/a-question-of-compactness-in-the-geometry-of-numbers

Comment: Also worth noting, the even easier case: the minimum of $S\mapsto\operatorname{vol}(S)/\Delta(S-S)$ is actually known among two-dimensional convex bodies (the triangle).

Comment: Looking again at Sergei's answer to the other question, it seems like what you're asking for here should fail: let T=S∪(−S), then among all S′ such that T=S′∪(−S') (and therefore Δ(S)=Δ(S′)) we minimize the volume by letting S′ be the intersection of T with a half-space through the origin. Since this minimum is never achieved so long as the origin is in the interior, the minimum of vol(S)/Δ(S) is never achieved. Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess T doesn't have to be bisectible into two convex regions, but, still, I don't see a good reason why the minimum should be achieved.

Comment: @Yoav: Thanks for your input. I don't see why the min should be achieved either and I'm starting to suspect it is not. What puzzles me is that no one seems to mention this.  